# onfocus html js

Tags: javascript, html

`<textarea onfocus="this.style.display='block'"></textarea>` и вот как тут указать, чтобы изменил в div блоке?

```
<div id="otv" style="display: none;">

</div>
```

Comment: А вообще смешивать логику с представлением (html-кодом) очень плохо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше держать скрипты отдельно от разметки. Дайте id текстовой области:

```
<textarea id="in-ta"></textarea>
<div id="otv" style="display: none;"></div>
```

И потом пишите скрипты:

```
<script>
var inta = document.getElementById('in-ta');
var div = document.getElementById('otv');
inta.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
function onFocus() {
    inta.style.display= "block";
    otv.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, для начала нужно начать с приветствия. Здравствуйте. С помощью document.getElementById(...);

```html
<div id="otv" style="display: none;">
  test
</div>

<textarea onfocus="document.getElementById('otv').style.display='block'"></textarea>
```

Comment: В жизни это, конечно, хорошо, но... http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/95/176892